# Theano import error: cannot import name Shape

Tags: python, theano

I am trying to import theano as

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
```

But its giving the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-ee4df930a2f4> in <module>()
----> 1 import theano
      2 import theano.tensor as T

/Users/pksaha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/__init__.py in <module>()
     53     object2, utils
     54 
---> 55 from theano.compile import \
     56     SymbolicInput, In, \
     57     SymbolicOutput, Out, \

/Users/pksaha/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from theano.compile.ops import (
      2         DeepCopyOp, deep_copy_op, register_deep_copy_op_c_code,
      3         Shape, shape, register_shape_c_code,
      4         Shape_i, register_shape_i_c_code,
      5         ViewOp, view_op, register_view_op_c_code, FromFunctionOp,

ImportError: cannot import name Shape
```

I am currently on the bleeding edge version of theano using the following command:

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
```

Comment: Update Theano. There was a bug fix that could help you. If that don't fix it, it is probably caused by multiple Theano version installed and that they get mixed. In that case, remove all Theano installation and reinstall.

Comment: Updating theano again with `pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git` solved the problem! Thanks @nouiz.